# I am using Event Bubble of Day Pilot Scheduler..how to show event details when click on event?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am using Event Bubble of Day Pilot Scheduler in mvc, i want to show complete details of my event what i have added when create event, how can i show.

My mvc code :

```
 protected override void OnEventBubble(EventBubbleArgs e)
        {
            e.BubbleHtml = "Event details for id: " + e.Id;
        }
```

my html :

```
 @Html.DayPilotBubble("bubble", new DayPilotBubbleConfig { CssOnly = true, CssClassPrefix = "bubble_default" })
```

And, i also declare in scheduler :

```
EventBubble = "bubble",
```